# R - GGplot2 Barplot - Fixing colors of color palette to same values over multiple plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, bar-chart, color-palette

I am about to make barplots showing the number of occurance of values. My problem is that I have 1 "Overview"-Plot containing all values, followed by detailed plots that are subsets of this overview plot. That means that these subset-plots do not contain the same number of values than the overview-plot.
[image]

That is a problem when compairing these plots, because the same values are having different colors in each plot. I want a fixed color for each value, that is always the same over all plots.

I know that you can assign a color for each value manually, but that is a lot of work. Is there any automatic way to do this? I have plots with much more different values than this.

This is my code:

```
numb = length(unique(subplot1$Diff))

mypalette<-rainbow(numb, alpha = 1)

ggplot(subplot1, aes(x=as.factor(Diff), fill=as.factor(Diff) )) + 
geom_bar( ) +
scale_fill_manual(values = mypalette) +
geom_text(stat='count', aes(label=..count..), vjust=-1) +
labs(x ="Difference", y = "Count") + 
theme(legend.position="none")
```

subplots

```
structure(list(ICD = c("F10", "F10", "F10", "F10"), xxA = c(-0.63, 
0.61, 0.57, 0.57), xxU = c(-0.52, 0.54, 0.5, 0.5), Diff = c(0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.1)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")

structure(list(ICD = c("F10-F19", "F10-F19", "F10-F19", "F10-F19", 
"F10-F19", "F10-F19", "F10-F19", "F10-F19", "F10-F19"), xxA = c(0.5, 
-0.64, -0.56, 0.51, -0.69, 0.59, 0.56, -0.67, 0.54), xxU = c(-0.5, 
-0.52, -0.65, -0.53, 0.82, 0.55, 0.56, -0.51, 0.51), Diff = c(1, 
0.1, 0.1, 1, 1.5, 0, 0, 0.2, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You could use a `facet` or set a "named pallete"  like c("0" = "red", "0.1" = "blue")

Comment: But that named pallete would not be automatically, right? I would need to write down every single color. What is a facet?

Comment: Here https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_grid.html, so you could create a single plot, separating each by a facet

Answer (score 1):

Vinícius Félix's comment is correct, but you don't need to write down every colour and the corresponding value. Here is one way to create a named colour palette (based on the values of the subplot2 dataset) that is consistent between different plots:

```r
# Load libraries
library(tidyverse)

# Example datasets
subplot1 <- structure(list(ICD = c("F10", "F10", "F10", "F10"), xxA = c(-0.63, 
                                                                        0.61, 0.57, 0.57), xxU = c(-0.52, 0.54, 0.5, 0.5), Diff = c(0.1, 
                                                                                                                                    0.1, 0.1, 0.1)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")

subplot2 <- structure(list(ICD = c("F10-F19", "F10-F19", "F10-F19", "F10-F19", 
                                   "F10-F19", "F10-F19", "F10-F19", "F10-F19", "F10-F19"), xxA = c(0.5, 
                                                                                                   -0.64, -0.56, 0.51, -0.69, 0.59, 0.56, -0.67, 0.54), xxU = c(-0.5, 
                                                                                                                                                                -0.52, -0.65, -0.53, 0.82, 0.55, 0.56, -0.51, 0.51), Diff = c(1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.1, 0.1, 1, 1.5, 0, 0, 0.2, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 9L), class = "data.frame")

# Create a 'named' colour palette
mypalette <- rainbow(5)
names(mypalette) <- sort(unique(subplot2$Diff))
mypalette
#>         0       0.1       0.2         1       1.5 
#> "#FF0000" "#CCFF00" "#00FF66" "#0066FF" "#CC00FF"
# Plot the data
ggplot(subplot1, aes(x=as.factor(Diff), fill=as.factor(Diff) )) + 
  geom_bar( ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = mypalette) +
  geom_text(stat='count', aes(label=..count..), vjust=-1) +
  labs(x ="Difference", y = "Count") + 
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(subplot2, aes(x=as.factor(Diff), fill=as.factor(Diff) )) + 
  geom_bar( ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = mypalette) +
  geom_text(stat='count', aes(label=..count..), vjust=-1) +
  labs(x ="Difference", y = "Count") + 
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>